# Kickstart file in virtualbox failing to boot

Tags: scientific-linux, kickstart

I want to write a bash script that creates a Scientific Linux 7.2 iso with a custom kickstart file, creates a new VirtualBox VM, and installs the iso onto that VM.

I have two scripts, `installBaseOS.sh` and `createKSISO.sh`.  Here are both:

`installBaseOS.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

../src/sh/createKSISO.sh
VM='testVM'
ISO=test/boot.iso

VBoxManage createhd --filename=test/$VM.vdi --size=16000 >> test/install.log 2>&1
VBoxManage createvm --name=$VM --ostype="Linux_64" --register >> test/install.log 2>&1

VBoxManage storagectl $VM --name "SATA Controller" --add sata --controller IntelAHCI
VBoxManage storageattach $VM --storagectl "SATA Controller" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium test/$VM.vdi

VBoxManage storagectl $VM --name "IDE Controller" --add ide
VBoxManage storageattach $VM --storagectl "IDE Controller" --port 0 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium $ISO

VBoxManage modifyvm $VM --ioapic on
VBoxManage modifyvm $VM --boot1 dvd --boot2 disk --boot3 none --boot4 none
VBoxManage modifyvm $VM --memory 1024 --vram 128
VBoxManage modifyvm $VM --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 wlo1

VBoxHeadless -s $VM >> test/install.log 2>&1
```

and `createKSISO.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir test/bootiso
sudo mount -o loop ../bin/SL-72.iso test/bootiso

mkdir test/bootisoks
cp -r test/bootiso/* test/bootisoks/

sudo umount test/bootiso && rmdir test/bootiso

chmod -R u+w test/bootisoks
cp ../src/cfg/ks.cfg test/bootisoks/isolinux

sed -i 's/append\ initrd\=initrd0.img/append initrd=initrd0.img\ ks\=cdrom:\/ks.cfg/' test/bootisoks/isolinux/isolinux.cfg

cd test/bootisoks && mkisofs -o ../boot.iso -b isolinux.bin -c boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -r -J -v -T isolinux/. .
cd ../..
rm -r test/bootisoks
```

And finally my kickstart file `ks.cfg`:

```
auth --enableshadow --enablemd5
install
reboot --eject
eula --agreed
cmdline
ignoredisk --only-use=sda
keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts='us'
lang en_US.UTF-8

logging --level=debug
rootpw testpass
timezone US/New_York
bootloader --location=mbr --boot-drive=sda
clearpart --all --initlabel
part pv.0 --size=1 --grow
volgroup rootvg01 pv.0
logvol / --fstype=ext4 --name=lv01 --vgname=rootvg01 --size=1 --grow

services --enable=NetworkManager,sshd

%packages
@base
@core
%end
```

If I comment out the `sed` command in `createKSISO.cfg` so that the boot process isn't looking for a kickstart file, the VM boots up into the live CD without issue, so I am fairly certain that I am creating the ISO correctly (mostly).

What happens if I add the ks=/ks.cfg to the boot is I get 3 lines on the boot log:

```
[ OK ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[ OK ] Reached target Paths.
[ OK ] Reached target Basic System.
```

Then it hangs for a couple minutes before I start getting `dracut-initqueue` timeout warnings.  After those I get to a `dracut` console and it tells me to look at `/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt`.  I don't have any way to get that file off the VM, and it is several hundred lines long, but I have copied the few lines directly before the start of the `dracut-initqueue` warnings appear:

```
localhost kernel: sda: unknown partition table
localhost kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
localhost systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 357 (plymouthd)
```

That last SIGRTMIN appears 4 times over about 3 seconds, then the timeout warnings appear about 1.5 minutes later.

I think my problem is caused by either a bad kickstart file, or the file isn't being found properly.  I have tried a number of example RHEL 7 kickstart files from the web to try to figure out if it is the first issue, but haven't had any luck.  What I would like to know is either the next step to debug why the kickstart of the VM fails, or what my issue is.  Once I have something working I plan on editing the kickstart file to end up with the system I actually want, but I have to get something working first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a rather simple (stupid) mistake.  Inside the `isolinux.cfg` file, on the same line modified by the `sed` command in `createKSISO.sh`, there is a key/value pair `root=live:CDLABEL=SL-72-x86_64-LiveCD`.  In about half of the tutorials I found online on creating a kickstarted ISO, the `mkisofs` command included the options `-V "Your CD Name Here"` or something similar, with no explanation as to the importance of this option.  I didn't care what my CD was called since it was temporary, so I ignored this.

However, for the created ISO to be bootable, the `root` label and the CD name must match.  If not the isolinux boot cannot find the OS to boot from the live CD.  The quick fix for this was I simply provided the name already in the `isolinux.cfg` to the `-V` option in my `createKSISO` script.  A more appropriate answer would be to make a custom name, then use `sed` to replace it in the `isolinux.cfg`.

Changing this, the newly created ISO boots, and the modifications made elsewhere in the scripts are seen in the file system.